# GTK: Using an Offscreen Window to investigate the rendered dimensions of widgets

Tags: gtk, ada, gtk3

I am utilizing a Gtk.Offscreen_Window to investigate the heights of various off-screen widgets in order to figure out where to place them on-screen based on their height. I managed to accomplish this with the following pseudo code.

```
procedure My_Proc 
is
    use Gtk.Offscreen_Window;
    use Gtk.Box;
    Offscreen : Gtk_Offscreen_Window := Gtk_Offscreen_Window_New;
    Box       : Gtk_Box := Gtk_Box_New ( Orientation_Vertical );
begin
    Offscreen.Set_Default_Geometry ( 1000, 1000 );
    Offscreen.Add ( Box );
    Offscreen.Show_All;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( Glib.Gint'Image ( Box.Get_Allocated_Height ));
end My_Proc;
```

This code will correctly tell me the height of Box. Note that my original code is a bit more complex than this but I've simplified it for the sake of this posting.

The problem here has to do with Offscreen.Show_All procedure. I know that this is not correct practice with an Offscreen widget since it cannot be shown like a normal Window. This is further emphasized by a warning that shows up on the console when this code is executed:

```
(main:26724): Gdk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.10.8/./gdk/x11/gdkwindow-x11.c:5531 drawable is not a native X11 window
```

Without including the Show_All function the size calculations will be incorrect (returns 1), so the Show_All function seems to be doing something important albeit a little too much. I believe the solution is as simple as finding out what runs the allocation calculations within the Show_All function and running that directly. Unfortunately I don't know what that function is.

So the bottom line is: **How do I correctly instruct the Offscreen_Window widget to perform its sizing calculations without using the Show_All function?**

Thank you.

*I am using Ada 2012, GtkAda (latest since mid 2015), Linux Kubuntu 14.04 but also expect this to run in Windows 7/8.*

Comment: Why not let the [container](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/LayoutContainers.html) handle the layout?

Comment: Because it does not return the correct size information using Get_Allocated_Height. Always returns 1 even though its size was set using Size_Allocate. The only way I've managed to return the correct height without connecting the widget to the main Window is by using a combination of Offscreen_Window and Show_All.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently learned that using the **Gtk.Widget.Size_Request** function was more correct for my situation than using **Gtk.Widget.Get_Allocated_Height** to find out the height of my newly spawned widget. Using this eliminates the erroneous use of **Gtk.Widget.Show_All** all together.

Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I am wary of this approach, as the result will depend on the particular geometry encountered, which may be incorrect in another environment. Instead, rely on the enclosing container to (recursively) size nested container, as discussed [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#geometry-management).